Поиск в списке словарей по одному или нескольким параметрам
Есть функция, которая принимает три параметра. Каждый из них может быть либо заполненным, либо пустым (""). Нужно из загруженного списка словарей (json_obj) получить необходимые данные (в match_books), если они подходят по непустым параметрам.
Начало функции:
    def find_book(cls, title, author, year):
        json_obj = cls.read_file()
        match_books = []

Как это наиболее грамотно реализовать, не создавая кучу if-ов?

я бы, наверное, посоветовал сделать эти параметры именованными, а затем просто отсеять внутри функции те из них, которые пустые. а по оставшимся уже делать выборку.

Вы таки приведите пример с "кучей if", чтобы было понятно, что вы вообще хотите. Тогда можно будет что-то придумать. Пока не очень понятна задача. А так то да, наверное через **kwargs должно быть довольно просто сделать.
